# behaviour of addViewInLayout() of ViewGroup in android

Tags: android, viewgroup

I am creating custom `ViewGroup` in which I am using `onLayout` method in which I call the `addViewInLayout()` of the `ViewGroup` but it is adding the `View` only horizontally.

How to force it to add `View` vertically like `ListView` is doing for Android

Looking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try specifying the position via

```
child.layout(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

If you have measured the other views in the view group, you should be able to get the bottom of the  bottom most view then

```
child.layout(left, viewAbove.getBottom(),right, viewAbove.getBottom()+heightOfTheChild);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be : `child.layout(left, viewAbove.getBottom(), right, viewAbove.getBottom() + heightOfTheChild);`